Javascript: How do I import and export async functions?
I am creating a weather app using front end only (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript) using NWS (National Weather Service) API, Google JavaScript Library API, Google Places API, and Google Geocoding API. I have created two async functions getCoordinates(region), and getWeatherData(latitude, longitude)
The entire program works without imports and exports. However, when I try to import and export the functions, it doesn't work. I am getting an error message

Uncaught (in promise) InvalidValueError...

with the Google JavaScript API library I am loading in the /html file where I use loading=async in the URL. However, I have no problem with without imports and exports.
In the .html file, I changed from
<script type="type/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

to
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>

I have not changed the Google JavaScript URL that I load as async defer .js file as the last line before body tag finishes.
Imports in index.js:
import getCoordinates from './location.js';
import { getWeatherData } from './weather.js';

Exports in location.js:
export default async function getDefault(region) { //code here }

Exports in weather.js
export async function getWeatherData(latitude, longitude) { //code here }


export default async function getCoordinates(region) { //code here } (getCoordinates instead of getDefault). Also, now the code has correctly been displayed above so the single and double quotes I have above do become significant in code. Also, I meant type='text/javascript' not 'type/javascript'

I have the correct code in my files. Everything works fine without imports/exports. No error messages and no warnings either. When I switch over to imports/exports, I get the above error message.

First of all, make the simple function an arrow function
export const getDefault = async (region) => {
// Your code here

}
and
export const getWeatherData = async (latitude, longitude) => {
// Your code here

}
If getDefault and getWeatherData are not default exports from their respective files, you should use curly braces when importing them.
import { getDefault } from "your file path";
import { getWeatherData } from "your file path";

However, if these functions are default exports, you would import them without curly braces:
import getDefault from "your file path";
import getWeatherData from "your file path";

I hope this will help you.

I tried this, but it didn't work though.

I hope someone can help. I tried both of the above two suggestions, but I'm still getting the same error.
